# Request has already been read - using graphql

Tags: quarkus

Getting lots of 'Request has already been read' issue with latest 1.5 quarkus and the new eclipse graphql microprofile. Typically get 5-8 failures, then the request (query or mutation) will get processed.

```
{\"details\":\"Error handling a57559fd-f5d3-4b50-b3a1-898d8fd6d4fa-45, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read\",\"stack\":\"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request has already been read\\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.checkEnded(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:591)\\n\tat io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.handler(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:304)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.ResumingRequestWrapper.handler(ResumingRequestWrapper.java:18)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper.handler(HttpServerRequestWrapper.java:79)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.ResumingRequestWrapper.handler(ResumingRequestWrapper.java:18)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.HttpServerRequestWrapper.handler(HttpServerRequestWrapper.java:79)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.handle(BodyHandlerImpl.java:86)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.BodyHandlerImpl.handle(BodyHandlerImpl.java:42)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$14.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:980)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$14.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:953)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$3.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:248)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$3.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:244)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1034)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:131)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:128)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.handleHotReplacementRequest(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:39)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1034)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:131)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:128)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:54)\\n\tat io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:36)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$7.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:351)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$7.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:348)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:122)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:113)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$2.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:72)\\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$2.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:63)\\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:330)\\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:369)\\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)\\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)\\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)\\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)\\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)\\n\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this issue is related to hot-reload when running in quarks:dev mode only.

Developers are aware and are working on a fix.

Comment: Hello, are you able to share the link to the conversations that the developers are aware of this? Thanks.?